# How to run site on laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have Installed WAMP, Installed Composer. In the cmd I writed command:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Laravel installer installed. Go to the folder `c:/wamp/www` with cmd and writed the command:

laravel new blog

has appeared a folder blog with these content:
[image]
And now that I do to open the main page of the site in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Point Wamp web server to a `public` folder of Laravel project. Find `httpd.conf` and change folders to something like this:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/public"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/public">
```

Restart Apache and run `localhost` in your browser. If everything is ok, you'll see Laravel start page.

Comment: @ Alexey Mezenin  1. how to point web server www folder to public folder project?   2. one Web server, only one project is raised?  3. 
Can not create a separate domain, such as the name laravel.loc ?

Comment: Use info from my post. Find `http.conf` inside Wamp folder end edit it. You can use one web server for many websites. To create separate domains, you should add Virtual Hosts to `httpd.conf` and add them to Windows's `hosts` file and restart Windows. Please read here: https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

Comment: I Changed `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` values to `public` folder laravel project. Restart server and on browser open link http://localhost , but it gives an error `( ! ) Warning: require(C:\wamp\www\blog\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\blog\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17`

Comment: Run `composer install` or `composer update`. If it'll not help, run `composer dumpauto -o`

Answer (score 1):

You can see the app in browser by simply

```
 http://localhost/blog/public
```

Or, you can create virtual host and point it to the 'public' folder of your laravel app and access site like

```
 http://yourlocalsitename.dev/
```

[Setup Virtual Host in WAMP](https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/)

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

Run `composer update` from your terminal (from your project root).

Comment: That's a wrong way to do it. There are a lof of "why doesn't it work" and "why am I getting this error" questions from newbies who setup WS like that.

Comment: @VipindasKS When i a open http://localhost/blog/public then error Warning: require(C:\wamp\www\avlodlar\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\avlodlar\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Comment: I said 'blog' just because you have installed in the name 'blog'. as per your previous comment, it seems like your project is 'avlodlar' ? see whether there is vendor folder and inside there is autoload.php. You must do `composer update` before trying to access the url.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yeah, this is the easiest to follow and well explained. https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

Comment: @Saahon see my updated answer. it might help you to access ` http://localhost/<your-project-name>/public`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use PHP's built-in development server. 
In the root directory of your project run `php artisan serve` and your site will be served on `http://localhost:8000/`